# Как парсить от тэга до тэга?

Tags: php, парсер

Написал скрипт для парсера мыл:

```
<?  
$handler=fopen('javabitz.txt','a+'); 
  for($i=1;$i<3000;$i++){ //парсим от 1 до 3000 
    $filename = 'http://www.***.ru/scr.php?num='.$i;  
    echo $i.". ";  
    $str = file_get_contents($filename);  
    preg_match_all('|href="mailto:([^"]*)"|is',$str,$out);  
    if(empty($out[1][0])) echo "Нету мыла";  
    else{  
      echo " get ".$out[1][0];  
      fwrite($handler,$out[1][0]."\n");  
    }  
    echo "\n";  
  }  
  fclose($handler);  
?>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы мы парсили от тега `<body>` до `</body>` в `preg_match_all`.

Заранее спасибо :)

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match_all('/<body[^>]*>(.*)<\/body>/', str_replace("\n", '', $str), $out);
// результат в $out[1][0]
```

Comment: спасибо) помогло ваше решение

Answer (score 0):

```
"|\<body\>href="mailto:([^"]*)\<\/body\>|"
```

кажется так...

Comment: только href="mailto: там лишнее.. вот если без нее.. вот так:


"|<body>([^"]*)</body>|"